# Short DHCP lease from ISP, causing problems with built-in NIC but not with pci NIC

Tags: dhcp-server, isp

ISP default lease is for 15 minutes. When this happens, built-in NIC release IP and gets `169.x.x.x` address and then immediately renews the IP from DCHP which will be the same IP as before (all happens within 5 seconds). My Public IP doesn't change unless I disable and enable network adapter.

When I use a PCI NIC adapter, I never lose IP, nothing changes. It is pretty stable.

I tried `"DontPingGateWay"` reg keys and other similar fixes but it doesn't help.
Every 15 minutes, I'm losing connection to gateway `(Cisco 2100 modem)` because of `169.x.x.x` address.

Any idea how I could troubleshoot this?

What actually happens that would make windows to use `169.x.x.x`? Something should maintain the IP or extend the lease time etc., No idea what is failing with built-in NIC

Don't know if its a driver issue, it all started 3 months ago and ISP doesn't give a woot about it.  I've also unchecked everything in NIC properties and keeping only IPv4.

```
   Built in NIC:
   Realtek RTKL8139/810x Family fast Ethernet
   Driver: Realtek/Microsoft  5/10/2013 - That is the latest there is.
```

Don't have a slot for PCI without compromising other hardware for now.

```
   PCI NIC:
   Cheap Zebronic card.
```

Comment: A packet capture from this NIC when it's renewing its lease would be great. It sounds like it's failing to renew over and over again, giving up (with a link local address) and then finally succeeding after five seconds. That's only a supposition, though. A capture with something like Wireshark would reveal more.

Comment: I'd just get rid of both of those lame excuses for NICs and buy something current.

Comment: Not sure if I interpreted it correctly, that din't sound like a techie response. 
What's something current? Buy a New Mobo just for this issue?
The issue is with motherboard built in adapter. The PCI adapter is new bought after I had this issue, but now I have other PCI device connected so no place for pci NIC.

Comment: Resolved. Seems to be a mac address issue. Updated the post.

Comment: Cool deal. Maybe copy that to an answer, and accept it yourself. I'd updoot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac address like 00:00:00:00:00:03 would cause this issue. DHCP server will send a negative acknowledge (DHCP NAK) and would not extend the lease.

Changing it to random mac address fixed the issue.

Comment: 1) Why use a random MAC-address rather than its default? (Now that you are no longer testing).  2) If you use random you will actually have to make sure that the least significant bit of the first octet is set correctly. So sort-of-random and not fully-random.

Comment: I don't know its original mac-address, could not retrieve it with `not present` selected. Why is least significant bit of first octet important? and what is wrong then?  Vmware starts with `00`. 
Afaik first 3 octets are for identifying vendor and I din't think it'd be of any use to ISP. Maybe their change was to identify proper vendor mac which means anything other than `00:00:00` and `ff:ff:ff` would be considered valid.